How can I set capability to systemd user service?
I have a systemd user service (not system service with a User=), But I need grant NET_ADMIN to this service, how to do it?
I can use fcap, but I'm trying to find another way.
Thanks.

I think you may be looking for the AmbientCapabilities option, describes in the Capabilities section of the systemd.exec man page.

@larsks But it only works for a system service, not user service.

Oh, sorry, I missed that the first time around.

User services can be defined by the user, so having a mechanism for adding capabilities the user does not have would be a security violation. The point of the service model is to have system services that can be activated from a user context.
